# Translation of confusing strating kanjis: 丅, 丄, 丂, 乁, 乀, 乆, '乛, 乢, 乧, 乭, 乮. 乯, 乶

Tags: translation

I am currently building a dictionary for japense words based on the corpus of texts. And in this dictionary I found confusing starting kanjis and words with them that I couldn't translate using different translation sites/ google. So, please, help me to understand wether these words have some meaning or I should delete them.

Prefixes and examples with them: 丄: 丄帊, 丄帋, 丄帒, 丄帟, 丄帠, 丄帡, 丄帣, 丄帤, 丄弌, 丄弍, 丄弐

丅: 丅夛, 丅夵,丅奒, 丅奜,丅奟,丅奣, 丅奧,丅奨,丅奺, 丅奿, 丅妋, 丅妎, 丅妏

乀: 乀彫, 乀怮, 乀恖, 乀憢, 乀戝, 乀拞, 乀掱, 乀摢, 乀擛, 乀斵

乁: 乁丄, 乁乛, 乁偁, 乁偄, 乁偐, 乁偒, 乁偔, 乁偗

乆: 乆丂, 乆丄, 乆丅, 乆乆, 乆乗, 乆乮, 乆乯, 乆乵, 乆乽, 乆乿

乛: 乛乢, 乛亶, 乛帪, 乛怱

乧: 乧丂, 乧丄, 乧丅, 乧丠, 乧乧, 乧乮, 乧偊, 乧偍

乢: 乢丄, 乢丅, 乢両, 乢乛, 乢乿, 乢偁, 乢偄

乮: 乮丄, 乮丠, 乮両, 乮乗, 乮乯, 乮乵, 乮乽, 乮亀, 乮亖

乯: 乯丂, 乯丄, 乯丅, 乯丒, 乯乗, 乯乧, 乯乮, 乯乯, 乯乲, 乯乵, 乯乽

乶: 乶乿, 乶偁, 乶偐, 乶偙, 乶偩, 乶偱, 乶偲, 乶側, 乶偵, 乶偺, 乶偼

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow, these are really not normal characters of the kind encountered in Japanese or even Chinese. In particular, 乮, 乯, 乶 are rare characters used to write Korean names only. You really need to confirm where your data is sourced from.

Comment: Googling some of them returned results in 1) Chinese, 2) a betting site spam, and 3) [possibly an encoding issue from translating a Japanese gal game to Chinese](https://github.com/Inori/FuckGalEngine/issues/4).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of these are valid Japanese words. There are a few easy Japanese kanji (e.g., 奨, 乗, 測), but all the rest are characters that are not used in ordinary Japanese text. I don't know what corpus you are using, but you may need to seriously doubt its quality.

(These don't seem to be valid Chinese words, either. Maybe this was caused by some encoding issue?)